# Global CSS does not work when building Next.js with Bazel

Tags: css, next.js, bazel

I build my Next.js app with [Bazel](https://bazel.build).
It works fine, but there is one problem:

When I import [`styles/globals.css`](https://github.com/flolu/nextjs-bazel/blob/5f2b10e7a6ae39d86c6ece7218b2444abde5ddc9/styles/globals.css) into [`pages/_app.tsx`](https://github.com/flolu/nextjs-bazel/blob/5f2b10e7a6ae39d86c6ece7218b2444abde5ddc9/pages/_app.tsx), Next.js throws this error:

```
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Please move all global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/css-global
Location: pages/_app.tsx
```

Which obviously doesn't make sense.

**[Reproduction](https://github.com/flolu/nextjs-bazel/tree/5f2b10e7a6ae39d86c6ece7218b2444abde5ddc9)**

1. `yarn install`
2. `yarn start:bazel` (http://localhost:3000, works just fine)
3. Now uncomment [this](https://github.com/flolu/nextjs-bazel/blob/5f2b10e7a6ae39d86c6ece7218b2444abde5ddc9/pages/_app.tsx#L2) line
4. `yarn start:bazel` (Error while buildling)

## Edit 1

After a suggestion by [Ulrich Thomas Gabor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3340665/ulrich-thomas-gabor), it turns out that [ctx.customAppFile](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/ab158c0aee53882457d2bac3e36b8ccf197166f0/packages/next/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/index.ts#L211) is `null`, which might be the root of the problem.

Here is a log output of `ctx` when building with Bazel:

```
{
  ctx: {
    rootDirectory: '/home/flo/.cache/bazel/_bazel_flo/e959037946bf226f3b911fa40ec62d93/sandbox/linux-sandbox/85/execroot/nextjs-bazel/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin',
    customAppFile: null,
    // ...
  }
}
```

## Edit 2

After some more debugging, I found the problem:

This [if statement](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/cd9bb986eba25006d4872e30eedf24ef5680bc6b/packages/next/server/lib/find-page-file.ts#L34) fails because of this error

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/home/flo/.cache/bazel/_bazel_flo/e959037946bf226f3b911fa40ec62d93/sandbox/linux-sandbox/186/execroot/nextjs-bazel/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/pages/_app.tsx'
```

If I patch Next.js to ignore this error, everything works fine!
**But how to prevent the `EACCES` error?**

Comment: Did you read the [provided link](https://err.sh/next.js/css-global) and the [subsequent link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css)?

Comment: Yes, I only import global styles it into `pages/_app`. And there is no problem with Component-Level CSS. Maybe I should mention that building natively, by running `next build` works fine. The issue only occurs when building under Bazel

Comment: Hm. Looks like [that if](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/ab158c0aee53882457d2bac3e36b8ccf197166f0/packages/next/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/index.ts#L211) fails. Maybe try debugging if `customAppFile` is passed through correctly and what its content is.

Comment: You are right, `ctx.customAppFile` is `null`. Now the question is why

Comment: Seems the variable is set [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/cd9bb986eba25006d4872e30eedf24ef5680bc6b/packages/next/build/webpack-config.ts#L573). Maybe you can find out what's happening there? Whatever is passed on [further down then](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/cd9bb986eba25006d4872e30eedf24ef5680bc6b/packages/next/build/webpack-config.ts#L1341) is that what you should see in `css/index.ts`. If this all seems correct (or wrong -- however one sees it), then next step is following the path further in the [nodejs-rules](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs) I guess..

Comment: I found the problem (see edited answer). Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Absolutely no clue. I guess since you have a minimal (not-)working example and an error message, this is a good time to open a Github issue there.